# Importing image into Tkinter - Python 3.5

Tags: python, image, import, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm majorly struggling to import an image into **Tkinter** for **Python 3.5**, this is for my A2 project and have hit a brick wall with every method of **importing a .JPG file** to my window. What I have below is my GUI layer for another window, based off another thread I found but didn't work at all. Any assistance appreciated.

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Skyrim: After Alduin")

photo = PhotoImage(file="Skyrim_Map")
map=Label(root, image=photo)
map.photo=photo
map.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Here's the error I receive:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Text_Adventure_Project\GUI_Interface-S_AA.py", line 14, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file="Skyrim_Map")
  File "C:\Users\Harrison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3393, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Harrison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3349, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Skyrim_Map": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Images usually have an extension. Try adding it. And be sure it is in same directory as script or use absolute path.

Comment: Put in the extension, and tried an sbolute path. Same error.

Comment: Do you actually have a file literally named `Skyrim_Map` with no suffix? Python absolutely won't say "no such file or directory" unless that is true.

Comment: No, there is a .jpg on the end of it, there just wasn't in the copy I put on here.

Comment: The error tells you it can't find the file, so either you are referencing the name wrong, or the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: An MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this is probably `open("Skyrim_Map", 'rb')`.  If so, forget tkinter and edit the path in this simple statement until it works.  Also, cut and paste the actual code you ran.  If you know that the posted code is not the same, correct it.

Answer (score 0):

First check the path if with the correct path still persist the error "no such file or directory" please edit and put the newest version of your code. 
If the error is "couldn't recognize data in image file" you can correct using PIL

```
 [...]
 from PIL import ImageTk

 [...]
 photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Skyrim_Map.jpg')
 [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`from PIL import Image , ImageTk
img = Image.open("your_img")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)`

Answer (score -2):

An other point of view :

class Application:

```
    ...
    self.photo=PhotoImage(file='picture.gif')
    self.item=self.can.create_image(200, 100, image=self.photo)
    ...
```

Hope to help ! ;)

Comment: This would only work with a handful of image formats such as `.gif` and `.png` excluding `.jpg` which the OP actually asks about.

Comment: Convert .jpg to .gif with Gimp and resize with right click on image and choice Image Resize ;)